# Equivalent Simplified Capacitor circuit

Tags: capacitor

[image: Capacitor Circuit]

Schematic created using [Multisim](http://www.ni.com/multisim/)

I'm trying to find the equivalent capacitance for the above diagram between nodes *b* and *c* but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding which capacitor is in series/parallel to which capacitor.

I know these equations:

Capacitors in series:

[image]

Capacitors in parallel:

[image]

From looking at the circuit I believe C4 and C3 are in series same as C1 and C2

Would the resulting two equivalent capacitors C4,3 and C1,2  then be parallel with C5 and C6 respectively?

Comment: Equivalent capacitor *between which two nodes*? Note that the circuit is completely symmetrical -- there are four nodes that form the vertices of a tetrahedron, and there's a capacitor along every edge. But the equivalent capacitance between any pair of nodes depends very much on the actual values of the capacitors.

Comment: For example, if \$\frac{C1}{C4} = \frac{C2}{C3}\$, then the value of C5 doesn't affect the result at all, since there's never any voltage across it.

Comment: @DaveTweed I never thought that any capacitor would be completely eliminated Thanks.
However because of the symmetry of this circuit, I am not sure
what pair of capacitors should I examine first?

Comment: @DaveTweed Is there a general motive for a certain pair of nodes

Comment: If all of the capacitors are equal, then you can simply erase C5. The resulting circuit is very straightforward to evaluate. The general equation for arbitrary values of capacitance is very messy.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem designed to break the usual method of series and parallel reduction of a problem. It needs something called nodal analysis, there are four nodes, so four simultaneous equations.   Does the problem state between which two nodes you'd like to know the equivalent capacitance?

Comment: @tomnexus Actually it wasn't homework per say
It was more like,
Our proffesor:"Now that you know the basics of equivalent circuits, let's view a tougher example that you won't be able to solve, and we will study more like this next semester."

But I was curious to know how to work on something like this.

Comment: @tomnexus It doesn't say which pair of nodes unfortunately

Comment: Without knowing which nodes to solve for you haven't got a question.

Comment: @Andyaka + Future readers, for the pair of nodes b,c can someone elaborate on the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some 'simplification of the circuit' 
That is the first simplification.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjZGjE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second simplification

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8v6xE.png)</sup>

The furthest simplification, assuming *C1/C4=C2/C3*

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvdYwG.png)</sup>

Here are the results
C1+C4=C3+C2=C/2

*nodes BC*= C6+2*(C/2)=C+C=2C

I think I have drawn the circuit correctly. 
Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) for more information on circuits like these.

Comment: @Wing you don't need all caps to be the same value only \$\dfrac{C1}{C4} = \dfrac{C2}{C3}\$ so yes you can eliminate C5 as it has the same voltage both sides so will have zero current through it.